# Git: should no fast forward option retain history?

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I am using Atlassian SourceTree and I have git set on BitBucket. My scenario is the following:

- I created a local branch (`enhancement` let's say it) of another branch, `develop` in my case.
- I made some changes and committed them to `enhancement`.
- Finally, I Merged `enhancement` to `develop` having SourceTree's "create a new commit even if fast-forward is possible" option set, hoping that this will effectively set --no-ff flag on.

I push to BitBucket and then I see this:

[image]

What I was expecting to see was commit ccaad53 right after 281f45e, without the intermediate 5 commits. Instead the history is retained. Is this supposed to be working that way, or am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT:** changed title to something more specific.

Comment: if I have understood your previous diagram, the result is fine, please look this reference: http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2013/09/fast-forward-git-merge.html

Comment: @kikicarbonell What do you mean "post set the order of the SHA identifier you'd expect"? I was expecting to see 281f45e and after that (atop of it) ccaad53. As it is now, but **without** the 5 intermediate commits. What I am actually asking is, if it's normal to see the history in a fast forward merge. I should change the title, it is misleading as I see it.

Comment: if you have 5 commit in local branch after the 281f45e and later you merged this branch with develop with --no-ff flag, the result it's as your image. Moreover if you was expecting only one commit after 281f45e with you changes, you need execute before: git rebase -i HEAD~5 to convert last 5 commit into one commit and then apply merge strategy.

Comment: my answer helped you?

Comment: @kikicarbonell Patience is a virtue, I was waiting for other responses as well -in vain as it proved. Your comment, the one that was suggesting rebasing could be helpful since it suggests a way to erase history and hence achieve the result I was looking for. You could have posted it as an answer. The link you gave, I saw it the first time you posted it, but it was not answering my question.

Comment: sorry, but i'm try to determine if my answer was sufficiently explicit. 
The reference published before, trying to explain the differences in merge strategy using -no-ff as parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 5 commit in local branch after the 281f45e and later you merged this branch with develop with --no-ff flag, the result it's as your image. Therefore, the response it's "yes", the graph result it's right.

Moreover if you was expecting only one commit after 281f45e with you changes, you need execute before: git rebase -i HEAD~5 to convert last 5 commit into one commit and then apply merge strategy.